# Exist a matcher in RSPEC that could do 'string.should eql("value" OR "value_2")'?

Tags: rspec

In RSPEC there's some matcher that could do some like:

```
string.should eql("value" OR "value_2")
```

A matcher that compares if a string is either equal "value" or "value_2"?

Thanks for your time! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. I solved the problem with another approach.

First, creating an array with the possible values:

```
possible_values_of_string["value", "value_2"]
```

then:

```
possible_values_of_string.should include(string_to_evaluate)
```